# Eclipse project generated with Maven has no facets

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have this plugin configured in the parent POM

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
                <triggers>auto,full,incremental,</triggers>
                <arguments>
                    <LaunchConfigHandle>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/Builder1.launch</LaunchConfigHandle>
                </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
                <triggers>auto,full,incremental,</triggers>
                <arguments>
                    <LaunchConfigHandle>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/Builder2.launch</LaunchConfigHandle>
                </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
        </additionalBuildcommands>
        <wtpContextName>${project.artifactId}</wtpContextName>
        <wtpversion>R7</wtpversion>
        <jeeversion>6.0</jeeversion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

When I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the child POM, the Eclipse project gets generated, but when I click on it in Eclipse and select `Properties > Project Facets` I get no facets, but the option to converted to a faceted form.

How can I fix this?

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 and Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meantime, I figured it out myself.

Just add to your pom:

```
<additionalProjectnatures>
    <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</projectnature>
</additionalProjectnatures>
```

to the `<configuration>` section of `<plugin>`.

Comment: This is for the maven-eclipse plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/provide-project-natures-and-build-commands.html

Comment: Yes, of course, as you can see I'm adding this into the plugin configuration part.